# B2C multiple Msal Instances handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, azure-ad-b2c

Am using two instances, one for normal login and two for connect to tenet in 'react'. Here am using useMsal()
method from the azure pkg to get the instance created. so, now i want to implement acquireTokenSilently() method for both. so, now am stuck here i need little help in implementing these methods. How to differentiate two instances and work on this methods ?

```
export const NormalLoginInstance = new PublicClientApplication(LoginMsalConfig);
```

```
var connectToTenantMsalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(
  connectToTenantMsalConfig
);
```